# Docker Compose Nested Environment Variable

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, environment-variables, docker-compose

I have an existing app that uses a app config file that looks like:

```
"ConnectionInfo": {
    "ServerName": "The Server URL",
    "DatabaseName": "The DatabaseName",
    "UserName": "The User Name",
    "Password": "The Password"}
```

Now, when I have a simple setting, say

```
"ConnectionString":"My Connection String"
```

I understand how to override it in the compose.yml file:

```
environment:
  - ConnectionString=what I want it to be
```

The question is, how do you set, say, the server name in the top?

Comment: Your app is the one reading the environment variables, so this would depend on what it is and how it works.  This has nothing to do with Docker Compose.

Comment: Why don't just pass the config file from host itself?

Comment: Ahm I have no problem reading the existing environment variable - but the Compose file (or the related .env file) can override the settings in the appsettings.json via the environment variable, but I only know how to do it for a non nested environment variable

Comment: @CharlesGallo Did you find the answer for it? I am also looking for a way to set variables on a nested config section

Comment: I never really did, and ended up moving on to something else

Answer (score 17):

Please use double underscore (__) as the following instead of a colon (:).

```
environment:
  - ConnectionInfo__ServerName=MyServerName
```

Please refer to [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=basicconfiguration#configuration-by-environment)

> For hierarchical config values specified in environment variables, a
>   colon (:) may not work on all platforms. Double underscore (__) is
>   supported by all platforms.

Answer (score 4):

You can set nested configurations using a colon to separate the nested sections:

To set the server name here:

```
"ConnectionInfo": {
    "ServerName": "override this via compose environment"
}
```

Override it like this:

```
environment:
  - ConnectionInfo:ServerName=MyServerName
```