# How to define an environment value witih : in name in docker compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I would like to pass an environment variable named `ABC:DEF` to a container defined in a `docker-compose.yml`.

How to do it?

If I write in a service definition

```
environment:
    ABC:DEF: ${ABC:DEF}
```

I got

`ERROR: Invalid interpolation format for "environment" option in service: "${ABC:DEF}"`

Edit: The goal of this question is to understand whether it is possible to use environment variables names which contain a `:` colon and how to properly define that in `docker-compose.yml`. A discussion what are the alternatives to using the `:` colon from the view of the "thing" running inside the affected container is not part of the question.

Comment: A colon is not a valid character in an environment variable name in Linux. This is a Linux requirement, not docker. The colon is a special character used to modify how variables are expanded.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I escape a $ dollar sign in a docker compose file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40619582/how-can-i-escape-a-dollar-sign-in-a-docker-compose-file)

Answer (score 8):

Use the following line instead of `ABC:DEF: ${ABC:DEF}`:

```
environment:
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: any-password
```

---

[**UPDATE**]:

> If `:` cannot be used in environment variables in your system, replace `:` with  `__` (double underscore).

[Configuration_in _ASP.NET _Core_Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/index?tabs=basicconfiguration&view=aspnetcore-2.1#simple-configuration)

So I think that would be something like this:

```
ABC__DEF: <asp-environment>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that does not help me to find a way how to properly define an environment variable containing a `:` colon, nor how to set it to a value of an environment variable containing a `:` colon.

Comment: @alik, I understand your mean now, but really is there an environment with containing the colon? I tried `$ A:B=1` terminally and encountered with an error!

Comment: Yes, there is. For example, ASP.NET Core uses colons to express hierarchy. Environment variable `ABC:DEF=GHI` equals to `{ "ABC" { "DEF": "GHI" } }` if expressed in JSON.

Comment: Just to clear things up, the container does not run ASP.NET Core. It's just an example that yes, there might be an environment containing the colon.

Comment: I am curious how to properly transfer the value from outside into the container via docker-compose. I can change the variable names if there is no such a way or if it is not nice enough.

Comment: @alik this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48356770/3702377) is similar problem with nested variable (JSON), so I think your problem is there in right side of colon (`${ABC:DEF}`)

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to define environment variables in docker compose as given below

1. Define it in compose file and pass the value via shell

[image]

```
    $ export TAG=v1.0

    $ docker-compose up -d
```

2. You can set env variables while running docker-compose

   docker-compose run -e TAG=v2.0
3. You can pass external variable file in compose file

[image]

4. You can define the default values in .env file

[image]

When you set the same environment variable in multiple files, here’s the priority used by Compose to choose which value to use:

1. Compose file
2. Shell environment variables
3. Environment file
4. Dockerfile
5. Variable is not defined

Comment: All in the docs https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file

Comment: Thanks, I've seen the docs. But I did not find a way how to properly define an environment variable containing a `:` colon, nor how to set it to a value of an environment variable containing a `:` colon.